# 2 table query only display certain rows

Tags: mysql

Table Structures:

- customers:

**`customer_id, first_name, last_name, street, unit, building, city, state, zip, phone, email`**

- work_requests:

**`work_requests_id, customer_id, work_type, description, request_time, completed`**

I have a php page that displays Work Requests using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers, work_requests WHERE customers.customer_id = work_requests.customer_id ORDER BY work_requests_id DESC LIMIT $startrow, 10
```

In the work_requests table, 'completed' has a value of `0 or 1`. `0 = work not done yet` and `1 = work has been done`. I only want to display Work Requests where completed has a value of `0` (i.e. work has not been done yet).  How do I do that?  FYI, `$startrow` has to do with pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add another condition?

```
SELECT   *
FROM     customers, work_requests 
WHERE    customers.customer_id = work_requests.customer_id 
AND      work_requests.completed = 0
ORDER BY work_requests_id DESC 
LIMIT    $startrow, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't shown code that displays these items, I think you mean you only want to SELECT Work Requests where completed has a value of 0

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers, work_requests 
WHERE customers.customer_id = work_requests.customer_id 
    AND work_requests.completed=0 # add this condition
ORDER BY work_requests_id DESC 
LIMIT $startrow, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers, work_requests 
WHERE customers.customer_id = work_requests.customer_id AND work_requests.completed=0
ORDER BY work_requests_id DESC LIMIT $startrow, 10
```